# Old behavior of DBMS_JOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle11gr2, dbms-job

In the old days prior to Oracle 12c, whenever a session of a DBMS_JOB gots killed the job was restarting by its own.

After our DBA installed a new version of Oracle 12c and we ported our application into this one we observed the above behavior is not the same.

A long running job was killed, prior 12c the job was restarting after a while on its own or we were forcing to run it via the NEXT_DATE procedure.

With the new version the job is not restarting even if we use the NEXT_DATE procedure or the database is restarted. The DBMS_JOB hangs around and you have to remove and re-create the job so that it is again running.

The problem is that our application was relying on the restart functionality of dbms_jobs.

Is there a specific internal process that was taking care of this restart or is there a parameter in the new database that enables/disables this feature. Or is this a Bug.

Thanks.

Comment: *The `DBMS_JOB` package has been superseded by the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.* - guess where I got this quotation. I copied it from Oracle 10.1 documentation which is 15 years old!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit from [Oracle 18 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/multi/using-oracle-scheduler-with-a-cdb.html#GUID-5BD1ACC9-D10D-4573-860F-5F8A65AE8554): *You can create a job using DBMS_JOB within a PDB, and it will work as before.*

Comment: @MarmiteBomber and the next sentence is:  "However, DBMS_JOB has been superseded by DBMS_SCHEDULER."  This might be a good time to update these procedures and remove dependencies on dbms_job

Comment: In the application the DBMS_Scheduler is also used. But this is the main job that spawns many many small DBMS_JOBS with the assumption that those are completed even if they are killed or failed. You may suggest to create chains of scheduled jobs for that purpose but the need is really simple to use the heavy "dbms_scheduler monster".